# Как добавить значения в json массив?

Tags: java, массивы, json

Как я могу записать новые данные в json массив? У Меня есть json файл, в нём есть массив Workers, который состоит из ключей name, age, pay, post и значений к ним. Как я могу записать в этот масив ещё 4 таких-же ключа? Использую библиотеку Simple Json

#### Мой Json

```
   {
  "Workers": [
  {
    "name": "Имя1",
    "post": "Должнось1",
    "age": 24,
    "pay": 20000
  },
  {
    "name": "Имя2",
    "post": "Должнось2",
    "age": 25,
    "pay": 16000
  }
    //Добавить вот так
    // {
    //    "name": "Имя3"
    //    "post": "Должность3"
    //    "age": "27"
    //    "pay": "15000"
    // },
]
}
```

#### Код, которым я читаю файл

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

 JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
 JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);

 JSONArray lang= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Workers");
 Iterator i = lang.iterator();
 while (i.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject) i.next();
    System.out.println("ФИО: " + innerObj.get("name") + "\n"
            + "Должность: " + innerObj.get("post") + "\n"
            + "Возраст: " + innerObj.get("age") + "\n"
            + "Зарплата: " + innerObj.get("pay") + "\n");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, почему вы используете библиотеку, которая уже 9 лет не поддерживается? Во-вторых, ваш json изначально составлен неправильно. Он должен содержать массив объектов Worker, а не объект Workers. Разумеется, вы можете создать класс Workers примерно такого вида:

```
@lombok.Data
@lombok.NoArgsConstructor
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
class Workers {
    private List<Worker> workers;
}
```

Однако в этом случае вы получаете бессмысленный класс-обертку над классом Worker. Можно сделать проще - получать сразу список объектов класса Worker.
Посему приведите свой джейсон к такому виду :

```
[
  {
    "name": "Имя1",
    "post": "Должнось1",
    "age": 24,
    "pay": 20000
  },
  {
    "name": "Имя2",
    "post": "Должнось2",
    "age": 25,
    "pay": 16000
  }
]
```

А теперь попробуйте это (вместо lombok вы можете сгенерировать геттеры, сеттеры самостоятельно, а можете использовать lombok , так проще):
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;

```
public class Main {

    private final static Gson GSON = new Gson();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Worker> json = readJson("1.txt", Worker.class);
        json.add(Worker.builder()
                .name("Имя3")
                .post("Должность3")
                .age(27)
                .pay(15_000L)
                .build());
        writeJson("2.txt", json);        
    }

    public static <T> List<T> readJson(String filePath, Class<T> clazz) {
        try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))){
            return (List<T>) GSON.fromJson(reader, List.class);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    public static <T> void writeJson(String filePath, List<T> params) {
        try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath))) {
            GSON.toJson(params, writer);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

}

@lombok.Data
@lombok.NoArgsConstructor
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
@lombok.Builder
class Worker {
    private String name;
    private String post;
    private Integer age;
    private Long pay;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно сработало. Использовал json simple, ибо советуют использовать её в учёбных целях